pymongo throws WinError 10048 when using multiprocessing
I am using pymongo in multiprocessing. I use 6 processes to calculate something and insert the calculation result into MongoDB.
import multiprocessing
import sys
import pymongo
import datetime

from multiprocessing import Pool


def query_records_by_date(ticker, start_of_day):
    """
    This function looks up records from MongoDB using parameters provided and return a list
    """
    mongo = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
    ...


def get_all_post_dates(ticker):
    """
    This function uses aggregations to get something from MongoDB and return a list of datetime.datetime objects
    """
    mongo = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
    ...


def process_ticker_attention(ticker, finish_num, lock):
    mongo_p = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/", connectTimeoutMS=600000)
    try:
        ticker_dates = get_all_post_dates(ticker)
        for date in ticker_dates:
            data = query_records_by_date(ticker, date)
            mongo_p['stock']['attention'].update_one({'date': date}, {
                '$set': {
                    'post_numbers': {
                        ticker: len(data)
                    }
                }
            })
        lock.acquire()
        finish_num.value += 1
        sys.stdout.write(f'\rfinish_count: {finish_num.value}')
        sys.stdout.flush()
        lock.release()
    except Exception as e:
        print('error!', e.__class__.__name__, e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mongo = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
    database_name = 'StockForum'
    lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
    finish_num = multiprocessing.Manager().Value('i', 0)
    tickers = mongo[database_name].list_collection_names()
    p = Pool(6)
    for t in tickers:
        p.apply_async(process_ticker_attention, args=(t, finish_num, lock))
    p.close()
    p.join()

I make sure that every subprocess creates their own mongo_client (as shown in the code snippet). ticker_dates in the process_ticker_attention function usually have some thousand elements.
The code runs well at first, but about 20-30 seconds later it throws the error:
error! AutoReconnect localhost:27017: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted (configured timeouts: connectTimeoutMS: 20000.0ms)

How should I fix this problem?

Finally figured out a fix, hope this would help somebody.
The problem occurs because get_all_post_dates is called too too many times by process_ticker_attention (thousands of times per ticker). The fix is to share one mongo_client inside each subprocess (NOT across processes).
def init_process(ticker, finish_num, lock):
    """Initialize a MongoDB connection for each worker process."""
    global mongo_p
    mongo_p = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/", connectTimeoutMS=600000)
    process_ticker_attention(ticker, finish_num, lock)

